# Redirect to post after submission with Gravity Forms?

Tags: redirect, plugin-gravity-forms, query-string

How do I redirect to a post after submission with gravity forms. It gives you the option to put in query string values but when I add `{post_id}/{Video Title:1}` I get `mysite.com/?123/name+of+post` and it just goes back to the homepage. My permalink structure is `post_id/postname` and `{Video Title:1}` equals the post name but it uses plus sings instead of dashes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use `p={post_id}` as query string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the query string to `p={post_id}`. WordPress will redirect it to the proper URI then automatically.